# CSS displaying only selective images?

Tags: css

I'm having a problem with my css and it's really winding me up. basically i have a 'background-image: url' set in my styles sheet and for some reason it won't display my file 'form_bg.png' but having just pasted a photo in the directory '1.png' this shows up. No matter what i try, whether i rename the file or anything like that 'form_bg.png' will not show?

Obviously the directory path is correct as it's pointing to '1.png' just not other files.

Can anyone let me know why this would happen?

Thanks

```
#main form {
    width: 440px;
    height: 450px;
    background-image: url(assets/img/form/icons.png) no-repeat;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: How does your file structure look like? Also, check in Chrome's Developer Tools/Firebug, is there any prominent errors there under the Network Tab?

Comment: Try deleting browser history and add qoutes like url("assets/img...")

Comment: If renaming the file to '1.png' still doesn't make it appear, consider a problem with the file itself

Answer (score 0):

using no-repeat in background-image is not correct. to use them in one line, use 'background' like this:

```
background: url('xyz.png') no-repeat;
```

and about your problem, try with absolute path of your image like this:

```
background: url('http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png');
```

Comment: Why -2 votes given to my reply I really didn't understand.

here is the w3.org documentation about background-image. Look to value : http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background-image

Answer (score 0):

I think that image is not a original png format that is maybe file extension only renamed so that the image is not shown to check this open that image in photoshop, if it is extension changed it will not opened.